# WP/PHP SoapClient: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error

Tags: php, web-services

Im trying to connect to a web service from php (WorkPress)whit soapClient and i'm getting this: 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.'

Any idea?

This is what I´m doing, the responce is a true or false.

```
$wsdlUrl = 'https://#####.svc?wsdl';
      $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
      var_dump($client->__getTypes()); 
      echo '</br>'; 
      $xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <tem:ExisteMiembro>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <tem:carnet>######</tem:carnet>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <tem:key>#######</tem:key>
       </tem:ExisteMiembro>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>');
    
    $params = new stdClass();
    $params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();
    $result = new SimpleXMLElement($client->ExisteMiembro($params));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I used this code instead and it works,

```
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 900);
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);


  try {

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $wsdlUrl = 'https://######.svc?wsdl';
    $soapClientOptions = array(
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);

    $checkVatParameters = array(
        'carnet' => '###',
        'key' => '###'
    );

    $result = $client->ExisteMiembro($checkVatParameters);
    print_r($result);
    return true;
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    var_dump("entro al msj de error");
  }
```